# Is it possible to disable SelectionArea in some children widgets? Flutter 3.3

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter 3.3 introduced the SelectionArea widget, which allows text selection across several different widgets.

It's really tempting to put it as above the main scaffold of a page. But that implies that the texts in the buttons are also selectable. This is annoying because it turns the cursor from a "click" to a "text selection".

Is there any way to say that we don't want a particular widget to be included in the SelectionArea?

[image]

Answer (score 14):

`SelectionContainer.disabled(child: ...)` should disable that behaviour over its `child`, according to [`SelectableRegion` documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SelectableRegion-class.html).